# PHP header.php not connecting to a subfolder

Tags: php, header-files, subdirectory

Many of the connections with CSS is in my header.php file. For example, in the header.php file:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I make a new subfolder, and all the PHP links are messed up. Expected. So I change this:

```
<?php include("/includes/header.php"); ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php include("../includes/header.php"); ?>
```

And it's working! But, all PHP links in the header.php aren't working - such as my style.css.

How do I fix this?

Comment: try to check the check the links if its correct.. and how did you know that the `include` was working and the css files were not?

Comment: Try using the complete path of the CSS file.

Comment: Use full path on the style sheet, eg: `<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` (only added a `/`)

Comment: For css try href="../css/style.css"

Comment: Please share your entire folder structure as image.